# Taking (patch) the delta from svn to git

Tags: git, svn, diff, git-svn

We have a Gerrit repository which was in sync with similar svn repo till some point in time. Now gerrit is behind by 4 commits. I need to take those 4 commits from svn to gerrit.

I tried multiple options I found here.

What I tried:

cd to svn repo and

```
svn diff -r r844:r944> myfile.patch
```

(Is there any other way to get all changes after a particular revision r844? )
copied that patch to a common location and

```
patch -p0 < myfile.patch
```

But what happened was - the changes were applied, but the commit history was not copied. This change was showing as one commit in the git after I did  *git add, git commit* locally.

Is there a way where we can replicate the commit history as well from svn to gerrit(the delta changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use [`svn diff`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/diff/) with the [`--git`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.git) option.